# How to measure fractal dimension of surf figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, dimension, fractals

I have a surf figure which is obtained by `surf` function of matlab. I want to calculate  `fractal dimension` of this using box counting dimension. How do i get ? surf image is
`Surf(x,y,z)`. I have tried to measure but height of Z is not picking up.
Can anybody help me .?

Regards
Dams

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Some examples and code what you tried would be useful.

Comment: I am trying to calculate this surface fractal dimension using box counting. http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38945-fractional-brownian-field-or-surface-generator

Comment: still not clear what is your actual problem.

Comment: I want to measure this surface figure. How can move forward to measure because it gives x=500 y=500 and z=500*500,moreover z is height from -3 to 3. if i take only z for measuring height is not picking up. If i take x y z then dimension problem occurs. Can you suggest me?

Comment: Experts any ideas ..??